# Comparing 2 pandas dataframes and outputting inequivalent values Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a piece of code in `pandas` where it gets 2 data frames `Unix,Unix2` compares them and outputs the range of indexes where there are differences. For example index 1 has `1444311780` for `Unix` and `1444311790` for `Unix2` the values of `Unix` and `Unix2` are different so it would make index 1 to be the starting range. Ending range would be the last consecutive value of an inequality so which would be for index 2 which compares `1635686040` and `1635686034` with `Unix, Unix2` respectably.

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd 

Unix= pd.DataFrame([1444311600, 1444311780, 1635686040, 1635686200, 1635686220])
Unix2 = pd.DataFrame([1444311600, 1444311790, 1635686034, 1635686200, 1635686230])
```

Expected Output:

```
first       last        
1           2  
4
```

Comment: I don't understand where your numbers are coming from. The only place `Unix` and `Unix2` overlap is the first value.

Comment: sorry about that it should be good now index 3 should have been equivalent too

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find the start and end index of every unequal streak. Try this:

```py
# Compare Unix to Unix2, row-by-row
s = Unix[0] != Unix2[0]

# Assign the group number. Every time `s` flips from True to False
# or vice-versa, make a new group
t = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

# Filter for the groups whose members are all True
u = t[s]

# For those groups, find the min and the max index of their members
result = u.index.to_series().groupby(u).agg(['min', 'max'])
```

Output:

```
   min  max
0          
2    1    2
4    4    4
```